# Kendo UI Grid in a Splitter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, splitter

I've got a splitter in my layout, to display informations.

My display is good, but when I had my grid in my index.html (which is called in my layout by @RenderBody() ) , my splitter isn't well displayed anymore ...

Everything is on a single page, without splitter ...

Any ideas ?

EDIT :

Yes sorry .

There's my Controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private static string path = @"C:\LogIngesup\log.xml";

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        DataTable logs = Write_Log.Read.loadXML(path);

        return View(logs);
    }
}
```

There my layout :

```
    <body>
@(Html.Kendo().Splitter()
      .Name("vertical")
      .Orientation(SplitterOrientation.Vertical)
      .Panes(verticalPanes =>
      {
          verticalPanes.Add()
              .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "middle-pane" })
              .Scrollable(false)
              .Collapsible(false)
              .Content(
                Html.Kendo().Splitter()
                    .Name("horizontal")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 100%;" })
                    .Panes(horizontalPanes =>
                    {
                        horizontalPanes.Add()
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "left-pane" })
                            .Size("230px")
                            .Resizable(false)
                            .Collapsible(true)
                            .Content(@<div>@RenderPage("~/Views/Home/Calendrier.cshtml")</div>);

                        horizontalPanes.Add()
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "center-pane" })
                            .Content(@<div class="pane-content">
                                <section id="main">
                                    @RenderBody()
                                </section>
                            </div>);

                        horizontalPanes.Add()
                            .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "right-pane" })
                            .Collapsible(true)
                            .Size("220px")
                            .Content(@<div class="pane-content">
                                @RenderPage("~/Views/Home/XML.cshtml")
                            </div>);
                    }).ToHtmlString()
              );

          verticalPanes.Add()
              .Size("70px")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "bottom-pane" })
          .Resizable(false)
          .Collapsible(true)
          .Content(@<div class="pane-content" style="text-align:center">
             <p>Application développée par : Dan</p>
          </div>);
      }))
</body>
```

And eventually my index.html :

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "LogApp";
}

@model System.Data.DataTable

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")    
    .Columns(columns => {
        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn column in Model.Columns)
        {
            columns.Bound(column.DataType, column.ColumnName);     
        }
    })    
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
)
```

I'm aware about any suggestion on my code :)

Furthermore I've got an issue :

When I try to add this in my grid (index.html):

```
.DataSource(datasource=>datasource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(10)
)
.Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
```

I can't go to other page, and can't select a row ... Can you help me ?

(It works when I write directly the url : localhost\?Grid-page=2)

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No,I haven't got any errors. My display works perfectly without the grid (I've got a column on the left with calendar, a column on the right, and a normal display in the center empty). When I add it, everything is melting. Normal : Calendar | Empty | Right Column After : Calender
Grid
Right Column

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when putting a Kendo UI Splitter inside a Kendo UI Tabcontrol.

When the Tabcontrol was made before the Splitter it was making this problem, but when I just reversed the order it worked fine.

i.e I changed from:

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#ManagementMenu").kendoTabStrip();
    $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
        panes: [
            { size: "200px", resizable: false},
            { size: "500px", collapsible: false}
        ],
    });
}
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#splitter").kendoSplitter({
        panes: [
            { size: "200px", resizable: false},
            { size: "500px", collapsible: false}
        ],
    });
    $("#ManagementMenu").kendoTabStrip();
}
```

and the problem was fixed.